# Query count of children, grandchildren of each grandfather by joining 3 SQL tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, group-by, left-join

I have the following 3 tables:

**Parents table**

```sql
id   names
------------
1     john
2     William
```

**Children table**

```
id  parent_id   names
----------------------
1     1          Thomas
2     1          Alfie
3     2          Henry
```

**Grandchildren table** which points to `Children table`

```
id  parent_id   names
----------------------
1     3          Harry
2     1          Joseph
3     1          Adam
```

I want to get the names of each grandfather with respective count of children and count of grandchildren.

I tried the following, but got wrong counts:

```sql
SELECT Parents.Id
      ,Parents.[name]
      ,COUNT(Children.Id) as children
      ,COUNT(Grandchildren.Id) as grandchildren 
  FROM Parents
  LEFT JOIN Children 
    ON Parents.Id = Children.ParentId
  LEFT JOIN Grandchildren
    ON Children.Id = Grandchildren.ParentId
  GROUP BY Parents.Id
          ,Parents.[name]
```

What may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should count the distinct children for each parent because the joins may return more than 1 row for each child.
As it is your query there is no need to count distinct grandchildren but if you decide to add more joins then you should also do that too.

In any case use the keyword `DISTINCT` (and aliases for the tables to make the code more readable):

```
SELECT p.Id, p.[name], 
       COUNT(DISTINCT c.Id) children, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT g.Id) grandchildren 
FROM Parents p
LEFT JOIN Children c ON p.Id = c.ParentId
LEFT JOIN Grandchildren g ON c.Id = g.ParentId
GROUP BY p.Id, p.[name];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are just missing a DISTINCT keyword . your query should be like

```
select  Parents.Id, Parents.[name] , COUNT( DISTINCT Children.Id ) children, count(Grandchildren.Id) grandchildren 
from Parents
left join Children on Parents.Id = Children.ParentId
left join Grandchildren on Children.Id = Grandchildren.ParentId
group by Parents.Id, Parents.[name]
```

see [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=46ac1fdecd068adad48d4f51eafd1283)